# Projector is not detected by Ubuntu desktop

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, projector

I'm using an Epson EB-S9 projector and it is connected using a USB cable to the Ubuntu system, but the problem is that the system does not detect it. Below is some information regarding my system:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Output is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

sudo lshw -C video
```

The output is:

```
    *-display 
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 02
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:42 memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f160(size=8)
```

I'm thinking that the necessary drivers might be missing. How can I install them?

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler solution : Use the VGA input**

If this is not an option, you can always try the following:

**Step 1 Identify your adapter**

- `lsusb` can be used to identify your adapter
- The contents of `/var/log/syslog` just after plugging-in your adapter may contain some information, like is a driver loaded, or if a problem happened (firmware missing, ...).

**Step 2 - Fix the problem**

Once your adapter is really identified, you can search on the internet which USB-to-display adapter it is, and if there is a driver available for your favorite Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Open "monitors" using unity and press "detect monitor" to discover the newly added monitor to detect.

Connection is done using usb so use `lsusb` to cheek the connection.

Comment: I already tried how you have suggested,but system is unable to detect the projector,while it working fine in windows.